# UWP :How I can do H.264 encoding of raw video frames and get encoded frames

Tags: video, uwp, h.264

Hi I am new to **UWP** programming. 
We have an existing video call application, which we are porting for Windows in UWP.
Our existing system designed such a way that, camera raw frames (YUV frames) feed to video encoder(H.264 OR H.263) and encoded video data will be packetized and sent to network.

To get YUV camera data, I am using **MediaCapture** and **MediaFrameReader** as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader

But, I am not able to find API's , to encode these video frames and get encoded video frames.

Please help me, how can I get encoded video frames in UWP

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that you can't do this in C#.  I haven't been current with media stuff lately, but as of a few years ago, you had to do all of the video conversion stuff using Media Foundation (MF) in C++.

[Media Foundation Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/media-foundation-programming-guide)

I tried (and only half-succeeded) to make an MKV codec back when one didn't exist and that's what I had to turn to.  These codecs are basically black boxes and MF will automatically pick the codec required for *decoding* video.

For writing your own codec (or making an existing codec work with MF), you'll have to turn to this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj872764.aspx).  The problem is it uses WRL instead of the newer C++/WinRT.  But oh, well.

Also, if you want to see my terrible attempt to make an MKV codec, go take a look here:  https://github.com/limefrogyank/MKVSource
I was/am a novice at C++ and a complete noob at MF, too.  But it worked... kind of.

### Edited Feb 2, 2019

Just to be sure, have you seen this?  Apparently, you can transcode video much more easily now using built-in tools:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaTranscoding

But to incorporate your own codec, you can follow this tutorial to combine something you create using MF with UWP.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/wrl/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-store-app-using-wrl-and-media-foundation?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thank you Mr . Lee McPherson for your detailed answer. Any way I am developing in C++/WinRT not using C#. I have one major concern for using MediaFoundation. As I see, it will work for desktop only. So, if I want to use App on other than desktop it wont work, isn't it? unfortunately, my code will go to Surface

Comment: No, it does work with UWP.  You can ship a UWP app with a codec that is registered in the app manifest.  Let me see if I can find the relevant sample and update my answer...